# Some details about a proposition of Wall

Tags: at.algebraic-topology, homotopy-theory

Let $X$ be a connected CW-complex.  For a given map $\phi‎ :‎X\longrightarrow Y$‎, ‎the mapping cylinder of $\phi$ is defined by $M_{\phi}:=Y\bigcup_{\phi} (X \times \{ 1\})$‎. ‎Denote $\pi_n (M_{\phi},X \times \{ 1\} )$  by $\pi_n (\phi)$‎. ‎The map $\phi$ is called $n$-connected if $X$ and $Y$ are connected and $\pi_i (\phi)=0$ for $1\leq i\leq n$‎. ‎Recall that an element of $\pi_n (\phi )$ is represented by a pair of maps $\alpha‎ :‎\mathbb{S}^{n-1}\longrightarrow X$ and $\beta‎ :‎\mathbb{D}^n \longrightarrow Y$ with $\beta|_{\mathbb{S}^{n-1}}=\phi \circ \alpha$‎.

‎Let $X$ be a CW-complex‎. ‎Then conditions $\mathcal{F}_i$ and $\mathcal{D}_i$ on $X$ are defined inductively as follows‎:

‎$\mathcal{F}_1$‎: ‎the group $\pi_1 (X)$ is finitely generated‎.

‎$\mathcal{F}_2$‎: ‎the group $\pi_1 (X)$ is finitely presented‎, ‎and for any  2-dimensional finite CW-complex $K$ and any map $\phi‎ :‎K\longrightarrow X$ inducing an isomorphism of fundamental groups‎, ‎$\pi_2 (\phi )$ is a finitely generated module over $\mathbb{Z}\pi_1 (X)$.

‎$\mathcal{F}_n$‎: ‎the condition $\mathcal{F}_{n-1}$ holds‎, ‎and for any $(n-1)$-dimensional finite CW-complex $K$ and any $(n-1)$-connected map $\phi‎ :‎K\longrightarrow X$‎, ‎$\pi_n (\phi )$ is a finitely generated $\mathbb{Z}\pi_1 (X)$-module‎.

‎$\mathcal{D}_n$‎: ‎$H_i(\tilde{X})=0$ for $i>n$‎, ‎and $H^{n+1}(X;\mathcal{B})=0$ for all coefficient bundles $\mathcal{B}$.‎‎‎‎
‎

C.T.C. Wall in the paper "Finiteness conditions for CW-complexes" proved that ‎if a CW-complex $X$  satisfies $\mathcal{D}_2$ and $\mathcal{F}_2$ and $\pi_1 (X)$ is a  free group‎, ‎then $X$ has the homotopy type of a finite wedge of  1-spheres and 2-spheres‎.

Here is the proof: We can find a finite bouquet $K$ of 1-spheres, and a map $\phi :K\to X$. inducing an isomorphism of fundamental groups. since $X$ satisfies $\mathcal{D}_2$, $\pi_2 (\phi)$ is a finitely generated projective $\mathbb{Z}\pi_1 (X)$-module. Now sicnce every fintely generated projective module over free groups is free, $\pi_2 (\phi)$ is a finitely generated free $\mathbb{Z}\pi_1 (X)$-module. So we can attach  a finite set of 2-cells to $K$, necessarily with trivial attaching maps, to make $\phi$ a homotopy equivalence.

My question: Why $\pi_2 (\phi)$ is a  $\mathbb{Z}\pi_1 (X)$-module? $\pi_2 (\phi ):=(M_{\phi},K \times \{ 1\} )$ is not abelian generally. As you see, Wall even mentioned it in the condition $\mathcal{F}_2$: "$\pi_2 (\phi )$ is a finitely generated module over $\mathbb{Z}\pi_1 (X)$".